# How do I resize a texture in SDL?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have this function:

```
void Texture::render(int x, int y, int w, int h, SDL_Renderer *&renderer, double angle, SDL_Point* center, SDL_RendererFlip flip)
{
    // Set a destination value to -1 to keep the current value
    if (x < 0) { x = rect.x; }
    if (y < 0) { y = rect.y; }
    if (w < 0) { w = rect.w; }
    if (h < 0) { h = rect.h; }

    // Create destination rectangle
    SDL_Rect dstRect = { x, y, w, h };

    // Render to screen
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, texture, &rect, &dstRect, angle, center, flip);
}
```

It works. It creates an image of the correct size at the location I want. But I want to add a chunk of code where it resizes the texture itself to be the size given in the destRect.

Comment: You don't resize texture, you create new ones. This sounds like an XY problem, why do you want to resize a texture?

Comment: @Nelfeal because I don't want to have to resize the texture every time I render it. But alright, thanks. I'll go look for how to resize via copying to a new texture.

Comment: But you aren't supposed to resize a texture every time you render it. The third argument to `SDL_RenderCopy`/`SDL_RenderCopyEx` lets you render the part you want.

Comment: And if you want to *scale* the texture, `SDL_RenderCopy` automatically does that, just change the destination rect (the fourth argument).

Comment: @Nelfeal So the srcrect parameter is the chunk of the texture you want to copy? I thought it had to be the entire image. That's really good to know. Thank you.

Comment: Check [the wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy). Why would you need to provide both the texture and its size, when you can ask the texture itself for its size ([`SDL_QueryTexture`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_QueryTexture))?

Comment: @Nelfeal I'm using QueryTexture to store the rect. I use it in a few places, so it just made more sense to grab it once and store it in a rect instead of calling it over and over again. Thanks for helping me out! This is the first time I'm working with SDL, so everything is unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 0):

So, anyone who finds this and reads the conversation I had with Nelfeal in the comments will see that I had a misunderstanding of how SDL_RenderCopyEx works. There's no need to resize the texture. If you need to do something like that, you can just use the dstRect when you copy it.

Actually, as far as I can find, there isn't a method to resize the actual texture itself. I'm sure one exists, but it's definitely not something people are commonly using. Which is usually a sign that it's a bad idea.

I've tweaked my code to try and simplify it, for anybody who's trying to do something similar to me:

```
void render(SDL_Renderer *&renderer, SDL_Rect *dstRect=NULL, SDL_Rect &srcRect=NULL, double angle=0.0, SDL_Point* center=NULL, SDL_RendererFlip flip=SDL_FLIP_NONE);
```

```
void Texture::render(SDL_Renderer *&renderer, SDL_Rect *dstRect, SDL_Rect *srcRect, double angle, SDL_Point* center, SDL_RendererFlip flip)
{
    // Check to see if a destination was provided
    bool check = false;
    if (dstRect == NULL)
    {
        check = true;
        dstRect = new SDL_Rect();
        dstRect->x = 0;
        dstRect->y = 0;
        dstRect->w = SCREEN_WIDTH;
        dstRect->h = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    }

    // Check to see if the entire texture is being copied
    if (srcRect == NULL) { srcRect = &rect; }

    // Render to screen
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, texture, srcRect, dstRect, angle, center, flip);

    // Free dstRect
    if (check) delete dstRect;}
```

And it looks like this when using the function:

```
bgTex.render(renderer);
blobTex.render(renderer, &blobDstRect);
```

Comment: You don't need any of those `if` blocks. If `dstRect == NULL`, `SDL_RenderCopyEx` will render to the entire rendering target. If `srcRect == NULL`, it will render the entire texture. The wiki explains it in [Function Parameters](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopyEx#function_parameters).

Comment: Correction: if `rect` is not the texture's rect, you still need that `if`. But if it is, then your function is effectively just wrapping a call to `SDL_RenderCopyEx`. Well, unless `renderer` is not the window renderer (or `SCREEN_WIDTH` and `SCREEN_HEIGHT` aren't the window dimensions)...